# Definition of Subspace of a Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Following is the definition of subspace of a vector space in Hoffman linear algebra book:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$. A subspace of $V$ is a subset $W$ of $V$ which is itself a vector space over $F$ with the operation of vector addition and scalar multiplication on $V$.

**My interpretation:** Two binary operation on $W$ are $+|_{W\times W}$ and $\cdot |_{F\times W}$. But $+|_{W\times W}(W\times W) \subseteq V$ and $\cdot |_{F\times W}(F\times W)\subseteq V$. Definition of vector space don’t requires us to check, $V$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication i.e. $x+y\in V$, $\forall x,y\in V$ and $c \cdot x\in V$, $\forall x\in V$, $\forall c\in F$. We just simply write, $+:V\times V\to V$ and $\cdot :F\times V\to V$, that makes closedness trivial (by definition of function). For $W$, closedness is not trivial. One “explicitly” requires following conditions to start/begin to talk about vector space: $u+v\in W$, $\forall u,v\in W$ and $c\cdot u\in W$, $\forall u\in W$, $\forall c\in F$. **Am I right? If yes, then how to precisely define subspace?**

**Edit:** Rephrasing definition of subspace to my taste

> let $(V,F,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over field $F$. $\emptyset \neq W\subseteq V$ is called subspace of $V$ if $(W,F,+|_{W\times W}, \cdot |_{F\times W})$ is a vector space over field $F$ $\iff$ $(1)$ $W\neq \emptyset$ $(2)$ $u+v\in W$, $\forall u,v\in W$ $(3)$ $c\cdot u\in W$, $\forall u\in W$, $\forall c\in F$ $\iff$ $(1)$ $0_V\in W$ (2) $c\cdot u+v\in W$, $\forall u,v\in W$ and $\forall c\in F$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137074/discussion-on-question-by-user264745-definition-of-subspace-of-a-vector-space).

Comment: @user264745 You phrase the additive identity axiom incorrectly in your comment. The way you phrase it the identity depends on $x$. The existential quantifier must precede the universal quantifier.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ohh….!

Comment: In general you are putting the quantifiers after the clause to which they apply, and while that may better mirror natural language, you should put them ahead of the clause so that their precedence and scope is clear.